# How to use Package Manager - trying to implement Hedwig

Tags: ios, swift, installation, ios-library

I am trying to add [Hedwig](https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig) Library to my Existing project but i am unable to do so.
I added other Libraries through **CocoaPods** but this one doesn't have it.

I am new to ***iOS Development*** and couldn't figure out what to do.

I even read other articles on this ([1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148832/introduction-swift-package-manager), [2](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/10/getting-started-with-swift-package-manager.html) and many others) but while reading it I get lost and couldn't understand what to do...

They tell me how to create a new Project but I already have one and I want to add the library to the existing one..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pretty self explanatory @Syed.

It tells you to add the repo to your Package.swift

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "YourAwesomeSoftware",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig.git", 
             majorVersion: 1)
    ]
)
```

then to execute a swift build

if you're not sure what the Package.swift is, refer to the official DOCs [Package Manager Swift](https://swift.org/package-manager/)

Comment: That shows you exactly what you need to do, hope I was able to help :)

Comment: Welll..... you see I created a project Using Xcode and now I want to implement that library in my Project.. the link you proposed Shows how to create a new Swift project (Correct me if I am wrong)...

Comment: ...Yes, you're wrong, simply open your console, navigate to your project and swift package init, a little reading and comprehension goes a long way.

Comment: Hmmm... It did work.. I was Confused that it might Destroy my existing project... Thanx... I m new to this and was a little afraid that it might make a new project... thanx again...

Comment: There are little things you can do to destroy your project haha, even adding 1000 pods won't destroy it.

have a good one @SyedAliNaqi, please up vote and select as correct if I helped :)